# Observing ViewWillAppear (Migrating RXSwift to combine)

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, combine

```
extension Reactive where Base: UIViewController {
    var viewWillAppear: Observable<Void> {
        sentMessage(#selector(UIViewController.viewWillAppear(_:)))
            .filter { [weak base] _ in
                if base?.isImageViewerPresented == true {
                    return false
                }
                return true
            }
            .mapToVoid()
    }
}
```

i want observe viewWillAppear like `self.viewWillApplerPublisher`
please help how to observe it

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are trying to figure out how to make a combine version of the RxCocoa feature?

Answer (score 2):

```
extension Reactive where Base: UIViewController {

    public var viewWillAppear: ControlEvent<Void> {
        let source = base.rx.methodInvoked(#selector(Base.viewWillAppear))
            .map { _ in }
      return ControlEvent(events: source)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know that I would wrap it in a ControlEvent, but this answer works.